# Amazon Route 53 to map an address like https://my-elb-address:88888/my-app-name

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, glassfish, routes, registrar

It is my first time with Amazon Route 53 and with a Registrar.

I can create an Amazon Route 53 Hosted Zone, and associate the delegate set in my Domain Registrar. It is also my first experience developing a JavaEE app.

I do have a running Amazon Elastic Load Balancer. I do have a server app accessed at a DNS address like https://:88888/my-app.

Please, could anyone clarify if (and how) it would be possible to have my domain address (www.my-domain.com.au) redirected to https://:88888/my-app ?

BR,

Rafael

Answer (score 3):

There's a few problems with that:

First, DNS cannot include port numbers.
Second, DNS cannot include a path.
Third, the maximum port number is 65535, so even if DNS did let you add a port number, that port number is too high.

You'll probably want to just send your domain directly to the server. Use apache to reverse proxy 80/443 to 8080/8009 (glassfish default ports for http/ajp), and just add a mod_rewrite rule that redirects `/` to `/my-app`.